# Calling HTML content from external JS file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an issue with what seems like a simple enough task. I have a web page where I need to load in and remove div content as the user clicks buttons. My code doesn't seem to work though.

The html:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/stylemain.css"/>

    <script src="assets/js/introduction.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">   
        <div id="content">
            <div id="slide1">
                <p>Here is the first trigger. It should look something like this</p>
                <p><input type="button" onclick="part2()" value="Click Me!" /></p>
            </div>        
        </div>
```

and the .js file:

```
function part2() {
    document.write("<div id="slide2">
                    <p>Here is the second trigger. It should be to the left</p>
                    <p>next line goes here</p>
                    </div>")
    }
```

It's coming up with a syntax error on line 2 of the js file (the document.write line) but I can't figure out why. I tried it both with and without quotations but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly cleaner solution is to use a combination of single quotes and double quotes:

```
function part2() {
    document.write('\
      <div id="slide2">\
        <p>Here is the second trigger. It should be to the left</p>\
        <p>next line goes here</p>\
      </div>'
    );
}
```

Note that if you want to use a string broken into multiple lines you must add the '\' in the end of each line to let JS parser know the string continues to the next line.

Comment: That worked. I didn't know about the "\". I'm quite new to this. Thanks! On a side issue I'm now having is this writes what is in the script on a blank white page ignoring any css. Is there a way I could get this to just write that html into the current page and have it read the stylings?

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the quotes:

```
function part2() {
    document.write("<div id=\"slide2\">\n<p>Here is the second trigger. It should be to the left</p>\n<p>next line goes here</p>\n</div>");
}
```